# Scripts are not running as expected while running them using selenium webdriver Grid

Tags: grid, webdriver

I want to run same script on three browser IE, Chrome and Firefox at a time (i.e., parallel). I am using the following code in `Testng.xml` file

```
 <test name="RunTests-1">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />     
    <parameter name="port" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" />
    <classes>
        <class name="Com.TestSuite.class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>  
<test name="RunTests-2">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />     
    <parameter name="port" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" />
    <classes>
        <class name="Com.TestSuite.class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="RunTests-3">
    <parameter name="browser" value="internet explorer" />     
    <parameter name="port" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" />
    <classes>
        <class name="Com.TestSuite.class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

while running it using TestNG, it is opening 3 browsers and executing the script. But the problem is while executing the script, it is performing some operations in the script(like entering a text in text field, clicking on a button etc) twice in one browser and not at all performing in other browsers. Please let me know what may be the reason for that.

Comment: Post the code which you used to invoke the browser.

Comment: Please refer to following google docs link for my code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s9cVQiAIvjT8ySXlLLzA1W1XqkCRcBZNFaPkxuWVTHk/edit

Comment: In the code where is `driver` instance declaration part and check weather you declared as a `Static` or not.

Comment: ya i have given as private static WebDriver driver; .... i have updated in above google docs link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare the variable as a `Static`. It will consider as a server side variable. In your case when you launch three browsers. It will use `single driver instance` for all the three browser sessions. For that reason alone the action is performing repeatedly in a same browser. To resolve the issue remove the `Static keyword` from the web driver definition.

Eg:

private WebDriver driver = null;

Comment: If my solution helps you then make it as a answer.

Comment: @Manigandan thanks a lot.Wish I could've seen it 5 hours earlier.:)Wish could give you 100 upvotes.