# Selenium and Parallelized JUnit - WebDriver instances

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, junit

### The setup

So, basically i am trying to achieve Selenium tests that run in parallel using JUnit.

For that i have found [this JUnit runner](http://hwellmann.blogspot.de/2009/12/running-parameterized-junit-tests-in.html). It works really well, i like it alot.

However, i am running into problems regarding the handling of WebDriver instances.

### What i want

Each WebDriver element should be created once for every class before `@Test` methods are executed.

Logically, i could use the classes constructor for this. Actually this is quite the requirement for my tests because i need to make use of the `@Parameters`so that i can create the WebDriver instance accordingly (Chrome,FF,IE ...).

### The problem

The problem is that i want the WebDriver instance to be cleared (`driver.quit()` ) after **a class** is done and not after **each `@Test` method** is done. 
But i cannot use `@AfterClass` because i cannot make WebDriver a static member, since each class instance has to use its own (otherwise tests would try to run in the same browser).

### A possible solution

I have found a possible suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067885/static-webdriver-instance-synchronization-in-java) by *Mrunal Gosar*. 
Following his advise i have changed WebDriver to be a `static ThreadLocal<WebDriver>` instead and then i create instances of it in each constructor using

```
 // in the classes constructor

driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
           @Override
           protected WebDriver initialValue() {
                 return new FirefoxDriver(); /
           }
};
```

Needles to say that i replaced every `driver.whatever` call with `driver.get().whatever` in my code.

Now, to address the ultimate purpose of this i also wrote a `@AfterClass` method that would call `driver.get().quit();` which is now accepted by the compiler, as the variable is static.

Testing this however leads to unexpected behavior. I have a Selenium Grid setup with 2 nodes running on a remote machine. I had this setup running as expected before, but now browsers are spammed all over and tests fail. (While 2 browsers should be running instead 8+ are opened)

The thread i linked suggesting this solution had someone commenting that it might be a bad idea to manually handle threads if already using a framework like JUnit.

### My Question

*What is the right design to do this?*

I could only think of

1. Make what is suggested here work
2. Write a single @Test annotated
   method that executes all other methods and then use @After to
   achieve the same as @AfterClass
3. Save the constructor parameter in a member variable and deal with the fact that i have to create a browser before each `@Test`annotated method is executed (Using `@Before` to create the WebDriver instance and `@After` to close the session)

I don't quite know if option 3 runs into possible problems though. If i close the session after each method, then the grid-Server might actually open a new session with an entirely new class on this node before this one has finished the previous ones. While the tests are independent of each other, i still feel like this is potential danger.

Is anyone on here actively using a multithreaded Selenium test suit and can guide me what is proper design?

Comment: A quick note: The problems i am experiencing with my current solution is bound to the fact that the class-constructor seems to be called for every class-method. So instead of having x amount of class instances, while x is the amount of parameters in the list returned from the `@Parameters` function, i actually have x*y where y = the amount of  `@Test` annotated methods inside of my class. 
I dont quite know what to do about that. Maybe the Runner i am using needs to be adjusted in some way, but i doubt that i can do a better job at it. Maybe this behavior is also necessary, i don't know.

Comment: I have no tried another solution involving ThreadLocal. With this, i have declared ThreadLocal<WebDriver> sWebDriver as a static member variable and have overwritten initialValue right there. Then i declare a "normal" `WebDriver myWebDriver;` also as member variable. Then, in `@Before` i do `myWebDriver = sWevDriver,get();` and use myWebDriver in the rest of the code. This works in such that only 2 instances of WebDriver are opened and the tests use the correct instance. However, in `@AfterClass` i defines `sWebDriver.get().quit()` which seems to work only for one of the two instances.

Comment: To make sure what you want to achieve: 
**1.** Write one class with T number of test cases (lets call it T1, T2, ...). 
**2.** Use JUnit parametrization (P browser types, lets call it P1, P2, ...) to  make JUnit run PxT number of test cases. 
**3.** For particular P type set of test cases (PxT1, PxT2, PxT3, etc) instantiate specific Px WebDriver only once and destroy it at the end. 
**4.** Parallelize execution of test cases but only on browser type (in other words, guarantee that no test with the same Px will run concurrently). 
/ Is that the case ?

Comment: Theoretically ... it would be possible that more instances of one browser are executed in parallel. So i need not to guarantee that a browser is only run once. HOWEVER, you bring up an interesting point and honestly, it would most likely be sufficient that 3 classes are ran in parallel (actually one class with 3 different parameters (browsers)). That would already deliver some speed and make things more sufficient. But the question remains. For those 3 instances of the class ran in parallel, how do i instance my webdriver so that i can still clear it in @AfterClass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general I agree that:

> it might be a bad idea to manually handle threads if already using a
>   framework like JUnit

But, looking at `Parallelized` runner you mentioned and internal implementation of `@Parametrized` in junit 4.12 it is possible.

Each test case is scheduled for execution. By default junit executes test cases in single thread. `Parallelized` extends `Parametrized` in that way that single threaded test scheduler is replaced with multi-thread scheduler so, to understand how this affects way `Parametrized` test cases are run we have to look inside JUnit `Parametrized` sources:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/r4.12/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java#L303

Looks like:

1. `@Parametrized` test case is split to group of `TestWithParameters` for
   every test parameter
2. for every `TestWithParameters` instance of `Runner` is created and scheduled 
   for execution (in this case `Runner` instance is specialized
   `BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters`)

In effect, **every @Parametrized test case generates group of test instances to run (single instance for every parameter) and every instance is scheduled independently** so in our case (`Parallelized` and `@Parametrized` test with `WebDriver` instances as parameters) multiple independent tests will be executed in dedicated threads for every `WebDriver` type. And this is important because allows us to store specific `WebDriver` instance in scope of the current thread.

Please **remember this behavior relies on internal implementation details of junit 4.12 and may change** (for example see comments in `RunnerScheduler`).

Take I look at example below. 
It relies on mentioned JUnit behavior and uses `ThreadLocal` to store `WebDriver` instances shared between test in the same cases groups. Only trick with `ThreadLocal` is to initialize it only once (in @Before) and destroy every created instance (in @AfterClass).

```
package example.junit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

/**
 * Parallel Selenium WebDriver example for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353996/selenium-and-parallelized-junit-webdriver-instances
 * Parallelized class is like http://hwellmann.blogspot.de/2009/12/running-parameterized-junit-tests-in.html
 */
@RunWith(Parallelized.class)
public class ParallelSeleniumTest {

    /** Available driver types */
    enum WebDriverType {
        CHROME,
        FIREFOX
    }

    /** Create WebDriver instances for specified type */
    static class WebDriverFactory {
        static WebDriver create(WebDriverType type) {
            WebDriver driver;
            switch (type) {
            case FIREFOX:
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case CHROME:
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            log(driver, "created");
            return driver;
        }
    }

    // for description how to user Parametrized
    // see: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests
    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public WebDriverType currentDriverType;

    // test case naming requires junit 4.11
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name= "{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> driverTypes() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { WebDriverType.CHROME },
                { WebDriverType.FIREFOX }
            });
    }

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> currentDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    private static List<WebDriver> driversToCleanup = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initChromeVariables() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
    }

    @Before
    public void driverInit() {
        if (currentDriver.get()==null) {
            WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.create(currentDriverType);
            driversToCleanup.add(driver);
            currentDriver.set(driver);
        }
    }

    private WebDriver getDriver() {
        return currentDriver.get();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchForChromeDriver() throws InterruptedException {
        openAndSearch(getDriver(), "chromedriver");
    }

    @Test
    public void searchForJunit() throws InterruptedException {
        openAndSearch(getDriver(), "junit");
    }

    @Test
    public void searchForStackoverflow() throws InterruptedException {
        openAndSearch(getDriver(), "stackoverflow");
    }

    private void openAndSearch(WebDriver driver, String phraseToSearch) throws InterruptedException {
        log(driver, "search for: "+phraseToSearch);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys(phraseToSearch);
        searchBox.submit();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void driverCleanup() {
        Iterator<WebDriver> iterator = driversToCleanup.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            WebDriver driver = iterator.next();
            log(driver, "about to quit");
            driver.quit();
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    private static void log(WebDriver driver, String message) {
        String driverShortName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(driver.getClass().getName(), ".");
        System.out.println(String.format("%15s, %15s: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), driverShortName, message));
    }

}
```

*It will open two browsers and execute three test cases in every browser window concurrently*.

Console will print something like:

```
pool-1-thread-1,    ChromeDriver: created
pool-1-thread-1,    ChromeDriver: search for: stackoverflow
pool-1-thread-2,   FirefoxDriver: created
pool-1-thread-2,   FirefoxDriver: search for: stackoverflow
pool-1-thread-1,    ChromeDriver: search for: junit
pool-1-thread-2,   FirefoxDriver: search for: junit
pool-1-thread-1,    ChromeDriver: search for: chromedriver
pool-1-thread-2,   FirefoxDriver: search for: chromedriver
           main,    ChromeDriver: about to quit
           main,   FirefoxDriver: about to quit
```

You can see that drivers are created once for every worker thread and destroyed at the end.

*To summarize, we need something like `@BeforeParameter` and `@AfterParameter` in context of execution thread and quick search shows that such idea is already registered as [issue in Junit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/45)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post, Thomasz! I upvoted it, but allow me to ask: Why do we have to initialize the WebDriver instance in the `@Before` method, instead of the `@BeforeClass` method?

Thinking of it, i guess i have misunderstood the way Parallelized worked. I thought that for every parameter in `@Parameters` there would be ONE class instance running it's tests with this parameter. Instead, it seems, that for every single test-method there is a thread running?

Comment: I think that is was ultimately confused me. Assuming that there would be 3 class instances for 3 Parameters in the Parameter-List, i thought that it must be the most efficient way to have the driver initialized ONCE for the class, in `@BeforeClass`. I thought that it would be inefficient to instance them x times for x amount of `@Test` methods. But, if i am right regarding the thread instancing, then every class-instance only runs for a single test-method. So then there is no difference if we do `@Before` or at `@BeforeClass`.
I hope i got that right?

Comment: Code in `@BeforeClass` is executed only once and by _main_ thread (also when `@Parametrized` is used). So yes, you would iterate and initialize all required WebDriver instances but cannot store them in `ThreadLocal` to be available later in worker threads execution context. At the other hand, cleaning is possible and simpler in `@AfterClass` - it's called once and we can just iterate on all registered `WebDriver` instances.

Comment: Oh, that is new. Very interesting, indeed.

Well, thanks a lot! I will definitely try to implement this. The whole thing has been worked on a lot since this question, but it now also uses such WebDriverFactory, so it should be easy to implement what you suggested.

Comment: It is quite easy to extract all parallel related logic to superclass, take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tdomzal/1765066b5876f4518074).

Comment: Yea, that's pretty much what i did with the test already and then later someone refactored the driver generation a little. However, we can still add the ThreadLocal thing.

It was hard to find a proper design for this, despite it being quite commonly applicable for Selenium. The tests gains a huge bonus from multithreading as they are heavily I/O dependent.  Hope if there is someone with similar questions he finds this thread and sees your well designed example code!