# Selenium and JUnit parallel test method execution in multiple drivers

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, parallel-processing

NOW: I have test project. Using maven-failsave-plugin I run jetty, then deploy there war and execute test scripts. 
TODO: I need to run in parallel in 5 webdrivers one method same time.
Or execute the same test class in 5 drivers same time.
It's like performance testing using Selenium ( bad choice, but it's requirement).

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31544625/1660507), it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how looks my ParrallelParametrized class.

```
public class ParallelParametrized extends Parameterized {
    private static class ThreadPoolScheduler implements RunnerScheduler {

        private ExecutorService executor;

        public ThreadPoolScheduler() {
            String threads = System.getProperty("web.driver.amount");
            int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(threads);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        }

        @Override
        public void finished() {
            executor.shutdown();
            try {
                executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
            executor.submit(childStatement);
        }
    }

    public ParallelParametrized(Class klass) throws Throwable {
        super(klass);
        setScheduler(new ThreadPoolScheduler());
    }

    public void filter(Filter filter) throws NoTestsRemainException {
        super.filter(new FilterDecorator(filter));
    }

    private static class FilterDecorator extends Filter {
        private final Filter delegate;

        private FilterDecorator(Filter delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
            return delegate.shouldRun(wrap(description));
        }

        @Override
        public String describe() {
            return delegate.describe();
        }
    }

    private static Description wrap(Description description) {
        String name = description.getDisplayName();
        String fixedName = deparametrizedName(name);
        Description clonedDescription =
                Description.createSuiteDescription(fixedName,description.getAnnotations().toArray(new Annotation[0]));
        for(Description child : description.getChildren()){
            clonedDescription.addChild(wrap(child));
        }
        return clonedDescription;
    }

    private static String deparametrizedName(String name) {
        if(name.startsWith("[")){
            return name;
        }
        int indexOfOpenBracket = name.indexOf('[');
        int indexOfCloseBracket = name.indexOf(']')+1;
        return name.substring(0,indexOfOpenBracket).concat(name.substring(indexOfCloseBracket));
    }
}
```

And that is my Abstact Test Class

```
public abstract class AbstractParallelBaseTest {

    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> CURRENT_DRIVER = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static List<WebDriver> DRIVERS_TO_CLEANUP = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());
    public static final long TIMEOUT = 100;


    protected static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(AbstractParallelBaseTest.class);

    static class WebDriverFactory {
        static WebDriver create() {
            WebDriver driver = null;
            try {
                LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
                logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.OFF);
                logs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.OFF);
                logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.OFF);
                logs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.OFF);
                logs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.OFF);
                logs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.OFF);

                DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;
                String webDriver = System.getProperty("web.driver");

                if ("chrome".equals(webDriver)) {
                    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy));
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
                } else if ("ie".equals(webDriver)) {
                    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy));
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(desiredCapabilities);
                } else if ("firefox".equals(webDriver)) {
                    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
                } else {
                    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnitWithJs();
                    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
                    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(desiredCapabilities);
                }

                driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
                driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1650, 1080));
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return driver;
        }
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public int currentDriverIndex;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static ArrayList<Object> driverTypes() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(getParams());
    }
}
```

On each implementation of tests I paste @RunWith(ParallelParametrized.class) and it works!